# Creating a segment for fixing water pipes and finding disconnected areas

Tags: qgis

I'm wondering if there is a tool for this problem. I'm using QGIS 2.14.2. Basically I want to select a pipe and find closest valves there is and to turn them off. After that I need to find all pipes that are disconnected from the main grid.

I need to solve which users/pipes are left without water when closing a segment from water network to fix a pipe.

This is a very simplified picture of water network, where blue dot marks the water source, red dots are valves and yellow dots users.

[image]

So when I select the broken pipe inside the area that needs to be closed, surrounded by valves, it would take them off the grid and show all the pipes that are not connected to the water source. In reality there is usually more pipes that need to be shut down for fixing the broken pipe.

For finding the disconnected pipes I'm thinking disconnected islands tool.

Comment: I searched for "pipe" and "hydr" in the plugin manager (in QGIS 3.4) and found these plugins that *might* work for you: QWater: Hydraulic design and analysis of water supply networks; WNT Open Source 3: A toolbox for water utility providers for QGIS 3; 
QEsg: Sanitary Sewage System Networks Design. I no longer have QGIS 2.14 installed so I don't know which ones are compatible with your version of QGIS.

Comment: @Jakko Were you able to solve the problem?